# Ubuntu 14.04 videos and games running slow

Tags: 14.04, drivers, radeon, performance, amd-processor

I have little problem with Ubuntu here. I was running Windows 8 and then i decide to make dual boot with ubuntu 14.04 (whitch is great system!) but when i boot to Ubuntu i have problems with system performance! For example, YouTube videos in Mozilla Firefox are slow, games for linux are running with low fps and PlayOnLinux is always unplayable! Can anybody help me and respond to me what can i do? I have dual core CPU AMD with 1,6 GHz (x2), 6 GB RAM, graphics card Radeon HD 6310M and about 700 GB hardisk. I think problem is my GPU... Anybody know good and stable driver for that card? Thank you soo much for any answers!

Comment: I don´t think your problem is related to dual booting at all. Seems more like a graphic card driver issue. Did you installed the proprietary drivers during your installation?

Comment: I dont know, but now i am running this driver: "Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)" and Steam in PlayOnLinux is slow as hell... Did i have bad graphic card or PC? Videos are now ok, but games are still unplayable. Or it is something in PoL?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an issue with your GPU drivers. Search for 'Additional Drivers' in Unity, and see what comes up. The propiatary drivers, while not GNU, would run a lot better.

Comment: I have installed "Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)" driver and videos are now ok, but Steam on PlayOnLinux are very slow...